# Find a Closed and Bounded set but not Compact in an incomplete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I am learning topology by myself:

Let $(X,d)$ be an incomplete metric space. Show that there exists a closed and bounded set $E \subset X$ that is not compact.

My attempt:

Since $X$ is incomplete metric space, then $\exists \{x_n\}$ in $X$ which is a Cauchy sequence but does not converge to any point in $X$.

Since $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy squence then let $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists M \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $\forall n, k \gneq M$, $d(x_n, x_k) < \epsilon$.

Let $B := \sup \{d(x_M, x1), ..., d(x_M, x_{M-1}), \epsilon\}$ then $E := C(x_M, B)$ is a closed and bounded set.

Since $\{x_n\}$ doesn't converge into any point in $X$, so $\forall x \in E \subset X$, $\exists$ bad $\epsilon$ such that  $\forall M \in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists n \gneq M$, $d(x, x_n) \gneq \epsilon$

Next, for the sake of contradiction, assume that $E$ is compact.

$$E\subset \bigcup_{x\in E} B(x, \epsilon_x) $$

where $\epsilon_x$ is bad $\epsilon$ for each $x$.

Since $E$ is compact then there exists a finite subcover, let's call it $A = \{a_1, ..., a_k\}$.

So I am stuck here. Could you guys please help me?

Comment: Why not try to find a bounded sequence with no convergent subsequence? And remember that 1. Cauchy sequences are bounded. 2. If a subsequence of a Cauchy sequence converges to $x$, the entire sequence converges to $x$.

Comment: I've just searched several bounded sequences but there are no convergent subsequences. But they are practical examples in specific metric spaces. This problem in jiri lebl, is more likely about general incomplete metric spaces.

Comment: What do you mean by $C(x_M, B)$? I am unfamiliar with this notation.

Comment: I'm sr for the confusion. It is a closed ball where $x_M$ is the center and B is its radius. $C(x_M, B) = \{x \in X | d(x_m, x) \lneq B\}$.

Comment: Use the rational numbers as your incomplete metric space. Then there are many examples.

Comment: Yeah, but in my opinion, it should be proved in a general case, rather than focusing on a specific metric space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the radius of the cover to give you more freedom this should be easier. Assume that the balls are of radius $\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_x$ instead.

Since you obtained a cover, there must be some $a\in A$ such that $\{ x_n \}\cap B(a,\epsilon_a)$ is infinite. I also claim that for any $N\in \mathbb{N}$, there exist $n,m>N$ such that $d(x_n,a)<\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_a$ and $d(x_m,a)>\epsilon_a$. Using the reverse triangle inequality you get a lower bound for $d(x_n,x_m)$. This contradicts the fact that $\{ x_n \}$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Yeah, ur proof is correct. I was so "obsessed" with only bad epsilons. Btw, many thanks.

Comment: @BlueTea You're welcome.